# Add Cell Metadata in Excel using OpenXml

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, ms-office, openxml-sdk

I have a scenario, where I want to add meta data to individual cells in Excel(.xslx) file. While going through Cell class in Open XML, I found that there are provision to store metadata for cell.

Refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell.aspx.

There are two attributes "cm" and "vm" which contains the index of the respective metadata.
How can I use these attributes using OpenXml to add metadata to cell. Excel file containing cell metadata or the code can help.

Update:
Please refer the below link : [Excel's handling of metadata](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c7f9747a-1d03-4415-97d4-d9aa58b4d240/bug-in-excels-handling-of-metadata-or-at-least-a-deviation-from-the-open-office-xml-specification).

Comment: Welcome on SO :) We provide helping on problems you get stucked with. So as more informations and specified problems you can describe from your own research, the mor the community is willed to help you.

Comment: Please refer the below link : [Excel's handling of metadata](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c7f9747a-1d03-4415-97d4-d9aa58b4d240/bug-in-excels-handling-of-metadata-or-at-least-a-deviation-from-the-open-office-xml-specification).